# Alter site logo path using drush

Tags: drush

I'm using drush to automatically build Drupal 7 sites.  I want to have each of the new generated sites use a custom logo.  I've been searching for a drush command that will allow me to set the path for the logo to a folder in the .../sites/*siteName*/files/  folder, but cant find one.  Can this be done with drush?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no such command AFAIK.

Logo path is stored in the variable table along with all theme settings as an array. For example, My Theme will store all its settings, including log_path, in the theme_my_theme_settings.

If you know all the settings for the theme you can use the vset drush command to set your theme settings variable with the right value.

This is an example of a theme settings variable value for a subtheme from [Zen theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/zen):

```
array (
  'toggle_logo' => 1,
  'toggle_name' => 0,
  'toggle_slogan' => 0,
  'toggle_node_user_picture' => 0,
  'toggle_comment_user_picture' => 1,
  'toggle_favicon' => 1,
  'toggle_main_menu' => 0,
  'toggle_secondary_menu' => 0,
  'default_logo' => 1,
  'logo_path' => '',
  'logo_upload' => '',
  'default_favicon' => 0,
  'favicon_path' => 'public://favicon_1.ico',
  'favicon_upload' => '',
  'zen_breadcrumb' => 'yes',
  'zen_breadcrumb_separator' => ' › ',
  'zen_breadcrumb_home' => 1,
  'zen_breadcrumb_trailing' => 0,
  'zen_breadcrumb_title' => 1,
  'zen_skip_link_anchor' => 'main-menu',
  'zen_skip_link_text' => 'Jump to navigation',
  'zen_html5_respond_meta' => 
  array (
    'respond' => 'respond',
    'html5' => 'html5',
    'meta' => 'meta',
  ),
  'zen_rebuild_registry' => 0,
  'zen_wireframes' => 0,
  'favicon_mimetype' => 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon',
)
```

If you want to use vset with an array see [this hint](https://www.drupal.org/node/664452#comment-5078776):

```
php -r "print json_encode(array('drupal', 'simpletest', 'leftandright', 'category'));"  | drush vset --format=json project_dependency_excluded_dependencies -
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make sure that the logo in your theme is using the default logo path (sites/all/themes/theme_name/logo.png). Then when you deploy, just copy the custom logo to that location with the filename "logo.png".